# Free Download Manager won't download YouTube videos in MP4

Tags: windows-8, firefox, firefox-extensions, youtube

Free Download Manager used to be able to download HD MP4 YouTube videos, but every time I try to download a video I only get FLV files.

I've set the videos to 1080p but they are downloaded as FLV (no sizes are given by the program either).

I'm using Windows 8 32-bit with Firefox, but I also tried Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please read [How to ask questions](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask). What operating system are you using? What is fdm? What format did you used to download in? What browser do you use?

Comment: I assumed you meant Free Download Manager (http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm) – if that's not the case, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I use a more simple solution to download a video from Youtube. Just add `ss` to the YouTube video link-address and the download will start.

With this, your link will look like: `http://www.ssyoutube.com/*****`

It works to download mp4 video files as well.

Comment: It is really the simplest way! I always do so. Thanks.